# Detecting long interval between events with RxJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs

I'm trying to capture long-press event in a model example. See the code below:

```
var Rx = require('rx'),
Observable = Rx.Observable;

var downEvents = [
// {'type': 'down', 'time': 50},
// {'type': 'down', 'time': 80},
// {'type': 'down', 'time': 140},
   {'type': 'down', 'time': 250}
];

var upEvents = [
// {'type': 'up', 'time': 60},
// {'type': 'up', 'time': 90},
// {'type': 'up', 'time': 150},
   {'type': 'up', 'time': 850}
];

var downStream = Observable.from(downEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
});

var upStream = Observable.from(upEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
}); 

var longClicks = downStream.flatMap(function(d) {
    return Observable.just(d).delay(400).takeUntil(upStream);
});

longClicks.subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log('long click: ' + x);
});
```

And it captures that single event. But if I uncomment previous events it will receive nothing. Could anyone please help me understand why is that?

With UI events the same code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zjor/0uqaw936/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was because of [takeUntil](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/takeuntil.md), so this code `Observable.just(d).delay(400).takeUntil(upStream);` means get elements from this observable `Observable.just(d).delay(400)` until the `upStream` produces a value.
If the delay is too big, then the upstream will produce all values before the delay expires. Therefore no statement was printed to the console.

Let's example your code once again:

With this instance, I set the delay time to 59 and a console statement is printed

```
var downEvents = [{
        'type': 'down',
        'time': 50
    },


];

var upEvents = [{
    'type': 'up',
    'time': 60
}, ];

var downStream = Rx.Observable.from(downEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
});

var upStream = Rx.Observable.from(upEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
});


var longClicks = downStream.flatMap(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return Rx.Observable.just(d).delay(59).takeUntil(upStream);
});

longClicks.subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log('long click: ' + x);
});
```

If I change the delay time to **61** then no output will be available

```
var downEvents = [{
        'type': 'down',
        'time': 50
    },


];

var upEvents = [{
    'type': 'up',
    'time': 60
}, ];

var downStream = Rx.Observable.from(downEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
});

var upStream = Rx.Observable.from(upEvents).flatMap(function(event) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(event.type).delay(event.time);
});


var longClicks = downStream.flatMap(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return Rx.Observable.just(d).delay(61).takeUntil(upStream);
});

longClicks.subscribe(function(x) {
    console.log('long click: ' + x);
});
```